# Get all the subsets of a set

Tags: python, algorithm, math, set

I'm trying to work out a recursive algorithm that would return me all the subsets of a set.
For example, if my function gets ['a','b'] it should return me ['a', 'b', 'ab', '{}']
But I got stuck in the moment when the function receives more than 3 elements. In case of ['a', 'b', 'c'] it gives me ['a', 'b', 'c', '{}', 'bc']. It would be okay if the first element was concatenated with each next except for '{}'. The answer should be ['a', 'b', 'c', 'bc', 'ab', 'ac', 'abc', '{}']

Here I gives my code.

```
def combination(iset):
    if len(iset) == 0:
        return '{}'
    elif len(iset) == 1:
        return [iset, combination([])]
    elif len(iset) == 2:
        return [iset[0]] + combination(iset[1]) + [iset[0] + iset[1]]
    return [iset[0]] + combination(iset[1:])
```

I want to do it using recursion, without any cycles. How is it possible to fix the issue? I've been thinking about an hour in it, but I didn't get to the answer.

UPDATE:
There's a fix I got to make, but it doesn't seem that elegant, does it?

```
res = [iset[0]] + combination(iset[1:]) 
return res + [iset[0] + x for x in res[1:] if x != '{}']
```

Comment: This will be expensive to do recursively for large sets. Are you open to non-recursive solutions?

Comment: I wasn't thinking about it, because the idea of making it using recursion interested me. The performance doesn't matter at all, it just for studying purposes.

Comment: What you want is a powerset. There is a recipe in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) documentation.

Comment: @jadrezz  Please don't put code into the comments. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77921680/edit) your post and add the missing code and remarks.

Comment: Yes, of course. But It is already worked out solution. My goal is to create my own algorithm. That's the point

Comment: I suggest writing a **recurrence formula** for this, and then writing both a recursive version and an iterative version, which both rely on the same recurrence formula. This will teach you the distinction between recurrence formulas and recursive programming, and will make you a more versatile programmer.

Comment: Also I suggest you also write a version that uses itertools; this way you can check your version for correctness by comparing the output of your function with the output of the version that uses itertools; and it will also teach you to use itertools, which is super useful in python.

Comment: Thanks. I finally stopped with the last update in my question. I found a nice code on C++ that was doing the same thing and the author managed to use only recursive method. I'll check how it works later. Thank you anyway for the participation